BigQuery - how to give granular permission
I have an app that is connecting to bigquery.
I need that app to be able to create dataset. On the dataset it created it should be able to: Create tables, add/delete data, start jobs.
For all other datasets it should only have read access.
Basically I need it to have all below permissions:
        bigquery.datasets.create
        bigquery.datasets.get
        bigquery.jobs.create
        bigquery.tables.getData
        bigquery.tables.list
        --- below that line are permissions I want to attach just to dataset that it created ---
        bigquery.tables.create
        bigquery.tables.delete
        bigquery.tables.updateData

But the last three (bigquery.tables.create/delete/updateData) should be only on datasets that were created by that app.
Is that possible to achieve?
